# What would be the value of $c$ where $c$ is the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, mass, mass-energy, wavelength

From the equation of $E=mc^2$, where $E$ is the energy, $m$ is the mass and $c$ is the speed of light, so from that we can get $c=\sqrt{Em}$, again from the equation of $\lambda=v/f$, where $\lambda$ is the wavelength, $v$ is the velocity and $f$ is the frequency, from that we can get $v=f\lambda$. Now consider the velocity $v$ is equal to $c$ in case of light in vaccum. In that case, combination of both this equation creates $c^2=\frac{Em}{f^2}$, but I knew that photon doesn't carry any mass. So it should be zero, thus the result will also be zero, which doesn't match in anyone form with the original value. So, what's the wrong thing that came up with this equation and moreover how the wavelength is connected to the mass!

Comment: The full equation is $E^2 = (m_{0}c^2)^2 + (pc)^2$

Comment: At the beginning you got the math wrong.
From $E=mc^2$ we get $c=\sqrt{E/m}$, but not $c=\sqrt{Em}$.

Answer (score 3):

The full equation is $$E^2 = (m_{0}c^2)^2 + (pc)^2$$

For light,  $m_{0} = 0$, then $E = pc$

The momentum of light is non zero, which can either be derived from photons, or electromagnetic theory.

If $p = \gamma m_{0}v$ (which is true for matter) then this equation reduces to $$E=\gamma m_{0}c^2$$

(Or $E=mc^2$, Where $ m=\gamma m_{0}$, or "relativistic mass")

$E=\gamma m_{0}c^2 $ is not valid for light, since light's momentum is not in the form $p = \gamma m_{0}v$

as $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{c^2}{c^2}}} =\frac{1}{0}$

Comment: Yet Einstein argued for E=mc^2 using the momentum transport of light. So, in his treatment, there is no difficulty with attributing relativistic mass to photons.

Comment: Please find the energy of light, using $E=\gamma m_{0} c^2$. No, you cannot use the apparent inertia of a box containing light, since that does not mean light has relativistic mass. Only means the boxes interaction with the photons gives the BOX  an apparent inertia.

Comment: In every sense, $\gamma$ is undefined for light.

Comment: Yet relativistic mass *is* defined for light.

Comment: Your approach has the strange property that mass appears and disappears

Comment: Relativistic mass of light is defined? Where? The only thing I have heard is that a box containing light has apparent inertia. I'm not sure what you mean by that last part. However mass is not a conserved quantity. Apparent inertia, does not mean it actually has mass.

Comment: Relativistic mass may be defined as E/c^2 for *anything*. A perfectly sensible definition, and one that conserves mass.

Comment: How much of the inertia of the teacup I'm holding is "apparent", as opposed to the inertia of its constituent quarks and electrons?

Answer (score -5):

Different meanings of the word "mass". Revisionists have redefined "mass" to mean "rest mass", thus sowing massive confusion. The photon has no rest mass. In revisionist relativity, E=mc^2 is not true.

For physics, it doesn't matter whether you use "mass" to mean "relativistic mass" or "rest mass" as long as you're clear and consistent. For historical continuity, it would be much better to have it mean "relativistic mass", thus preserving the seminal, beautiful E=mc^2.

Comment: How exactly are you going to apply your "beautiful" equation to a photon?

Comment: @hft The same way Einstein did a century ago when he argued for the universality of E=mc^2 by considering the transport of mass by light within a box. The same way the subject was taught a few decades ago.

Comment: And I'm sure the application of your equation to a photon is so *elegant* that it can *easily* fit into a single comment below this one. Go ahead:

Comment: @hft Einstein's box. You transmit a photon from one end, the box recoils, begins to move. You receive the photon at the other end, the box recoils again, stops moving (yes, I know about the infinite stiffness objection, but it doesn't make a difference, really). The box moves just as you would expect if you took an object of mass E/c^2 and moved it from one end to another. That object  was a photon. The revisionist way of analyzing this is equivalent but more abstract.